# Django modelformset exclude

Tags: django, validation, formset

Lets say I have a model with 2 fields: `user` and `money`. And I want to edit only users money fields.

If i create a `modelformset` and exclude for example `user` field from the form, then does it mean that if someone creates a false form, with user field included it will ignore it and save with bounded instance?

Or do i still need to validate something like this? And if, for example, someone still includes new form with new user in it how do I go about it?

Comment: If you exclude a field, it is not shown in the form that is rendered in your template; does that answer your question or is it something else?

Comment: :)) I understand that it is not rendered in my template. But basically if someone manually edits html, and send me the form where user is present then my edit form will also change and save user. Right ? So basically if don't somehow validate that scenario case someone may submit something i don't want ?

Comment: Well if you are using `POST` (which you should), then you must be using `CSRF` (which is on by default), which will prevent such cross site postings, but it is always good to validate user input. However, if you exclude the field, even if you pass it in; then the form will not validate.

Comment: CSRF is absolutely not relevant here.... I am not talking about hacking, i am talking just about simply changing values in html, or deleting some forms.  Imagine you have a formset with 5 identical forms which have 5 user instances bound to user fields so u can edit the form. Let's say you validate that all users in request.POST are distinct.  But now i delete 5th user, and in just html change first user to fifth user.  When you will start validation you'll say that everything is fine all users are different. But that fifth user i deleted wont even be in POST. And u'll have two 5th users in db

Comment: If you have _excluded_ the user, then it won't be sent to the front end in the from; and if you modify the form and then send in another field with the user ID, the form won't validate when you pass in the POST dictionary. Also, if you delete forms and the management form isn't updated, then your entire formset won't validate. However, you can always just try it out yourself.